# Updating text box value from combobox option

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I can't work out where I am going wrong with my code. When the user selects a value in the combo box, i want it to go to the Consultants table and grab the default rate for that consultant and stick it in the Hourly Rate text box. [This is the msg that I get when I update the combobox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNtBy.png)

```
Private Sub cmbConsultant_Change()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ''Requires reference to Microsoft DAO x.x Library
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "defaultFee * FROM tblConsultants WHERE ID = """ & Me!cmbConsultant & """"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
   Me.txtHourlyRate = rs!CountOfEndDeviceType
Else
   Me.txtHourlyRate = ""
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

You could use DLookup for this - much simpler:

```
Private Sub cmbConsultant_Change()

    Me!txtHourlyRate.Value = DLookup("defaultFee", "tblConsultants", "ID = '" & Me!cmbConsultant.Value & "'")

End Sub
```

However, most likely your ID is numeric, thus:

```
Private Sub cmbConsultant_Change()

    Me!txtHourlyRate.Value = DLookup("defaultFee", "tblConsultants", "ID = " & Me!cmbConsultant.Value & "")

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like a much more effective way to do things, but i get the error 3464: Data  type mismatch in criteria expression when I try to change the combobox value now. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I Think You need some `SELECT` Here

```
strSQL = "defaultFee * FROM tblConsultants WHERE ID = """ & Me!cmbConsultant & """"
```

It Should Be:

```
strSQL = "SELECT defaultFee AS [CountOfEndDeviceType] FROM tblConsultants WHERE ID = """ & Me!cmbConsultant & """"
```

Also Note, That [CountOfEndDeviceType] Must be a FieldName, SO I've put it in a Select statement.